# "Attempt to delete row from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before update"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to delete the rows that don't meet the criteria in the for loop. However, I'm getting and error that says: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update." I'v never seen this before and not sure why I am getting it.

My code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLabel.text = prices[indexPath.row]
    cell.descLabel.text = descs[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemImage.image = itemImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.userNumber = phoneNumbers[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.timeLabel.text = datesHours[indexPath.row]! + "hr"
    cell.distanceLabel.text = String(locations[indexPath.row]!) + "mi"
    cell.viewController = self




    self.theTableView.beginUpdates()

    for (index, number) in self.locations {
        if number <= 5 {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: number, inSection: 1)
            self.theTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        }
    }
    self.theTableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Why you're calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?? It's not a good idea

Comment: Victor what would you suggest I do? If I call redloadRowsAtIndexPath in another method, I can't access the values in my arrays

Comment: @theActuary That makes no sense. What arrays? You haven't made the lifecycle clear, because you probably haven't thought clearly about it. *What event* causes the rows to be deleted? Whatever event it is, you put the `for` loop in the handler for it. The only job of cellForRowAtIndexPath is to compute a cell *that is known to be in the table*. Nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are telling the table there will be more rows than you actually want to display and then deleting them after the fact.

Instead you should be checking if the elements in the array meet the criteria in (or before) `numberOfRowsInSection` and putting them into a different array that will actually be displayed so that the table knows how many rows will actually be displayed. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just use the newly create array that has the data that will actually be displayed.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.

        self.displayArray = []
        for (index, number) in self.locations {
            if number <= 5 {
               self.displayArray.Add(self.locations[index])
            }
        }
        return self.displayArray.Count
    }
```

I'm assuming your error has something to do with you trying to update the table in a method that is first trying to create it. You're trying to update something that hasn't fully been created.