# Swift3 collectionView 'attempt to delete item 1 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification, collectionview

My app crashed due to 'attempt to delete item 1 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'

I found other articles said that the data source must keep in sync with the collectionView or tableView, so I remove the object from my array: alarms before I delete the item in my collectionView, this works on didSelectItemAtIndexPath. But I don't know why this doesn't work.

I also tried to print the array.count, it showed the object did remove form the array.

```
func disableAlarmAfterReceiving(notification: UILocalNotification) {
    for alarm in alarms {
        if alarm == notification.fireDate {
            if let index = alarms.index(of: alarm) {
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: index, section: 1)

                alarms.remove(at: index)
                collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath as IndexPath])

                reloadCell()
            }
        }
    }
}

func reloadCell() {
    userDefaults.set(alarms, forKey: "alarms")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        print("Cell reloaded")
        print(self.alarms.count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: index, section: 1)` to `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: index, section: 0)`, and check. The exception itself is very self explaining.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016708/attempt-to-delete-row-from-section-1-but-there-are-only-1-sections-before-upda

Comment: try to call reloadData() when you delete object from array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having single section so you need to delete it from the `0` section. Also use Swift 3 native [`IndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath/) directly instead of [`NSIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath/).

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)

alarms.remove(at: index)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

**Edit:** Try to break the loop after deleting items from collectionView.

```
if let index = alarms.index(of: alarm) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    alarms.remove(at: index)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
    reloadCell()

    break
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, now it's doesn't crash but the cell is not deleting either.

Comment: @BryceChan you want to remove multiple item or single item from array n collectionView?

Comment: I want to remove single item from array and collectionView.

Comment: @BryceChan Check my edited answer and also what is `reloadCell` here?

Comment: should be `let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)` in the edit.

Comment: @VishalSingh Thanks for the correction. Edited answer for that

Comment: @NiravD Now I got this crash ''attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update''.

Comment: @BryceChan That section is still `0` I have already edited answer for it and can you please tell me what is `reloadCell` in your code.

Comment: `func reloadCell() {
        userDefaults.set(alarms, forKey: "alarms")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            print("Cell reloaded")
            print(self.alarms.count)
        }
    }`

Comment: @BryceChan Is your array count decrease after delete?

Comment: @NiravD Yes, it does.

Comment: @BryceChan May be you are in background delete item on main thread.

Comment: @BryceChan Have you delete cell on main thread like my edited answer, Is it working after that.

Comment: @BryceChan Welcome mate :)