# TableView ReloadSection Get Crashed?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete section 100, but there are only 7 sections before the update'
*** First throw call stack:

I'm Trying to make collapsable TableView WithAnimation.From Header did tap view it will call toggle section method.Ima working based on is it selected or not bool value.

```
class ExploreLocallyVc: UIViewController {
var headerViewMain = HeaderView()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
var ArrayOfCollapsable : [Int:Bool]? = [:]
var prevIousSelection : Int? = 100
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    tableView?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView?.sectionHeaderHeight = 60
    tableView?.separatorStyle = .none
   
}
}

extension ExploreLocallyVc:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 7
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if (ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] == true) {
        print("yes")
       return 4
    }
    else
    {
    print("No")
       return 0
    }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "q", for: indexPath)
     cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    headerViewMain = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as? HeaderView)!
    headerViewMain.titleLabel?.text = "\(section)"
    if (ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] == true) {
       headerViewMain.arrowLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
    }
    headerViewMain.section = section
    headerViewMain.delegate = self
  
    return headerViewMain
}
}

extension ExploreLocallyVc:HeaderViewDelegate
{
func toggleSection(header: HeaderView, section: Int)
{
    
    if (ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] == true) {
        print("yes")
       ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] = false
    }
    else
    {
        print("No")
        ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] = true
        ArrayOfCollapsable?.updateValue(false, forKey: prevIousSelection!)
    }
    tableView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    prevIousSelection = section
    print(ArrayOfCollapsable!)
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Attempt to delete row from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016708/attempt-to-delete-row-from-section-1-but-there-are-only-1-sections-before-upda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reloaded previous section first and reloaded changed section as below

```
 func toggleSection(header: HeaderView, section: Int)
{

    if (ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] == true) {
        print("yes")
       ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] = false
    }
    else
    {
    print("No")
    ArrayOfCollapsable?.updateValue(false, forKey: prevIousSelection!)
    if (tableView?.numberOfSections)! >= prevIousSelection!{
        tableView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: prevIousSelection!) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    }
    ArrayOfCollapsable?[section] = true
    }
    tableView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    prevIousSelection = section
    print(ArrayOfCollapsable!)
}
```