# How can I securely delete Rows at indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, indexpath

I think this Is a rather dumb question but I did not find any solution to securely delete Rows in my Table view.

```
calendarTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
```

I want to first check if there are any rows before I delete them because currently I get an error like this if I try to when there aren't any rows to delete:

> 'attempt to delete row 6 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'

My Array to display / hide looks like this:

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [
    ExpandableNames(isExpanded: false, names: ["Amy", "Bill", "Zack", "Steve", "Jack", "Jill", "Mary"]),
    ]
```

Comment: Delete from your data source array before you delete row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Attempt to delete row from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016708/attempt-to-delete-row-from-section-1-but-there-are-only-1-sections-before-upda)

Comment: how do you mean _securely_? however it is a simple policy you need to follow: delete the rows + remove the data from datasource as well; because they have to synced otherwise you get such an error message you just got.

Comment: I don't want to delete from the data source. I just want my table view to not display these rows anymore. This command gets called if I choose to hide the rows of a section.

Comment: I think you need to manage two arrays here. One as a table datasource and one for changes you made on table datasource array.

Comment: @Noodledew, the tableview's datasource __must__ be synced somehow – that is not an optional thing. there are various ways to do that, e.g. you can flag the items to be deleted and evaluate the datasource based on that, or you could create a completely different datasource for the tableview – it is matter of choice only.

Comment: Where you wrote the method `deleteRows`?

Comment: Its a function of UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

No need to manage two arrays or delete it from the datasource.
Just check if the number of Rows is != 0 before you delete it.

```
let numberOfRows = calendarTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
```

Answer (score 0):

Securely delete rows,You should ensure count of rows is same before you delete and after,total count == new count(delete after) + delete count